# What is CSharp where constraints on types for all built-in compiler variable types?

Tags: c#, generics

Built-in compiler variable types : int, float, double, short, ...
I need this to implement IsBetween

```
public bool IsBetween<T>(this T input) where T : [built-in compiler variable types] {
    return false;
}
```

Any alternative would be fine if there isn't exactly a direct way.

Comment: Do you want to prevent all value types from being used, or only primitive types? I don't think the latter can be achieved with type parameter constraints.

Comment: What are "built-in compiler variable types"?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I want only primitive types to be used

Comment: That's not a useful constraint, so it's no wonder nobody specified it.

Comment: @Mahdi Primitives or number types?

Comment: @ofstream number types

Comment: @Mahdi Built in, and numeric are completely separate. For example `BigInteger` is numeric but doesn't get any compiler special casing.

Comment: You might want to read this post: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html

Comment: @Mahdi What you're looking for is overloads. You could overload it to every type, or you could just overload it to double and decimal. Up to you.

Comment: @CodesInChaos The types which has been mentioned in first line of my answer. primitive and number types.

Comment: @BoltClock Primitive and numeric types. example is on first line of my answer

Comment: @Mahdi Primitive and numbers are orthogonal concepts. `bool` is primitive, but not a number. `BigInteger` is a number, but not primitive. (Primitive is a pretty useless concept in general, and I believe the C# spec doesn't use it at all)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `IsBetween` you don't need built in types, nor numeric types. You need types with an order, which implies implementing `IComparable<T>`:

```
public bool IsBetweenInclusive<T>(this T input, T lower, T upper)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return IsBetweenInclusive(input, lower, upper, Comparer<T>.Default);
}

public bool IsBetweenInclusive<T>(this T input, T lower, T upper, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    return (comparer.Compare(lower,input) <= 0)&&
           (comparer.Compare(upper,input) >= 0);
}
```

Comment: This was actually what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

If by "compiler variable types" you mean primitive types, there is no such restraint:

[MSDN - Contraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

You can use struct to *allow* most built-in types, but you could also define your own struct and it would be allowed.

I'm presuming you're building `IsBetween` to genericise the numeric comparison `a <= x <= b`.  If that's your intent, the way to do it generically is to use `IComparable<T>`.

```
public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T input, T lower, T upper) where T : IComparable<T> {
    return lower.CompareTo(input) < 0 && input.CompareTo(upper) < 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `where T : struct` to cover all value types

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: This will also allow the function to accept user defined value types, which the OP is attempting to exclude.

Comment: +1 Simpler and faster.

Comment: @Fuex Simpler and faster is irrelevant when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In C# there is no formal definition of what "primitive types" are; such a term is not mentioned in the specs.

There is no generic constraint that you can add that will restrict the input to only primitive types, because there's no way of knowing what those types might be.

The best you can do is have an overload of the method for each of the types that you want:

```
public bool IsBetween(this int input)
{
    return false;
}

public bool IsBetween(this double input)
{
    return false;
}

public bool IsBetween(this float input)
{
    return false;
}

//...
```

Note that due to implicit conversions between the operators, for example from `int` to `long`, from `single` to `double`, etc. you could optionally omit some of them and let the conversions handle it.

Comment: At the CLR level there is `Type.IsPrimitive`, but I never really got the point of it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you mean by *"built-in compiler variable types"*, maybe something like

```
public bool IsBetween<T>(this T input) where T : struct {
    return false;
}
```

could be suitable.